# Erro ao resolver dependências no Gradle: "Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath"

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

Estou enfrentando um problema ao tentar compilar meu projeto Android usando o Gradle. Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:
**Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.**

Aqui está o conteúdo do meu arquivo build.gradle:

** plugins {
id("com.android.application")
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
id("kotlin-kapt")
}

android {
namespace = "com.example.pokedex"
compileSdk = 34

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "com.example.pokedex"
    minSdk = 24
    targetSdk = 34
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
    viewBinding = true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
}
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
implementation("com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-view-model-compose:2.7.0")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0")
```

}
**